# JS on static domain can't call php file from subfolder on subdomain

Tags: php, jquery

Just had a question - I have this static cookieless domain from which I serve js, css, pics etc. But it seems like the js files have trouble calling php files which I stored in a subfolder of the subdomain on which the script is active; it works however when the php file is in the same folder and the file on which the js is active. Let me illustrate that.
I have following js file:

https://www.mystaticdomain/js/mydomain40/js/40/functionscript.js

This works fine on the following subdomain:

https://login.mydomain.com/index.php

Now, if I have a helper file to be called by the js script above in the same folder as the index.php is in, like this:

https://login.mydomain.com/helperfile.php

It works just fine and all the functions are executed without a glitch; however, when I put the same helper file into a subfolder of the subdomain, like this:

https://login.mydomain.com/core/helperfile.php

...It does not work whatsoever. All folder permissions are set to allow it (775) and the owner is also correct and set to be allowed to use the file. Is this merely a X-domain issue when files in the same folder do work or is there something else that I forgot to look at?

And it's also not an error in my js, as far as I can see; here's the code that calls the php:

(only the relevant part is put in here)

```
var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "core/helperfile.php");
```

I tried the full url https://login.mydomain.com/core/helperfile.php, /core/helperfile.php etc - the js doesn't seem to like any of these. But when I do just "helperfile.php" it works just fine. Any ideas? Thanks a million!

Comment: What is the url form with you do the request? For instance "core/helperfile.php" on "http://test.com/" simply leads to "http://test.com/core/helperfile.php" however the same request on "http://test.com/core/" points to "http://test.com/core/core/helperfile.php/"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As stated, the request is made from a js script which lives on my static domain. The helperfile is being called with: https://login.mydomain.com/core/helperfile.php; I tried /core/helperfile.php;  mydomain.com/core/helperfile.php; core/helperfile.php; ../core/helperfile.php; core/helperfile.php; virtually every combination - nothing seems to tickle jquery's fancy here.

Comment: Never mind - it has been fixed. Closing this question as it was something totally unrelated to filepaths. Giving Peter M a point for answering. The cause was that somebody had uploaded an empty file onto the core folder to which I had no access on the server up until now. Replaced the empty file with the correct one and now it works like a charm. Please, whoever can do this - please close this ticket and thanks Peter M for ansering it.

Comment: Thanks and good to hear you've got your problem solved.